# Generate request-example in Swagger codegen

Tags: code-generation, swagger, codegen

I'm attempting to write a new language module for [swagger codegen](http://swagger.io/swagger-codegen/). In my generated client, I would like to include an example request. An instance of this can be seen in [swagger UI](http://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet) under "Example Value"

[image]

The text itself doesn't seem to be contained in swagger spec for this service, but is constructed from the request object model, recursively de-referencing sub models.

Is there a straightforward way to generate this string within the codegen library? If I have to borrow code from SwaggerUI instead, is there a java implementation I can look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the UI is generating an example value for the model based on the schema.  You can use the `io.swagger.codegen.examples.ExampleGenerator` in your code to generate models and set them in the object before generating templates.

Comment: Thank you. ExampleGenerator was very useful. I'm having trouble getting which model to use, from an operation bodyparam. I'll probably raise a new question.